# How to create base dn on Open ds

Tags: ldap, opends

Im using OPEN ds 2.2 as my LDAP server currently i want a create a base dn like `dc=esamurdhiint,dc=lk` 
 i create following ldif file and run and i, having error on that

my ldif file

```
dn: dc=esamurdhiint,dc=lk
objectClass: domain
objectClass: top
dc: esamurdhiint
```

my command id

```
ldapmodify -h 10.136.78.27 -p 1389 -D "cn=admin,ou=system" -w changeit -a  -f /tmp/ldap.ldif

" adding new entry "dc=esamurdhiint,dc=lk"
ldap_add: No such object (32)
    additional info: The provided entry dc=esamurdhiint,dc=lk cannot be added because its suffix is not defined as one of the suffixes within the Directory Server ".
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
./dsconfig set-backend-prop --backend-name userRoot --add base-dn:dc=<<esamurdhiint,dc=lk>>
--hostname localhost --port 4444 --bindDN cn=admin,ou=system --bindPassword changeit
--trustAll --noPropertiesFile --no-prompt
```

Comment: Perfect. Just create the context entry afterwards and everything is done! :-)

Answer (score 2):

As Roshan indicated, you need to configure the suffix (base-dn) first and specify which database backend it will be in.
You may choose to add the suffix to the default backend (userRoot) or to a new backend.